# Remove shaded relief effect from an image

Tags: image-processing

Thank you everyone for your comments. This is my edited version of the question.

I've got a shaded relief effect map that is showing topography data of an area. 
Each color represent an elevation value which is shown in the legend located at the top center of the map. 
I evaluated

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVCAE.jpg"]
bm= PixelValuePositions[image, {33/255, 130/255, 145/255}];
Show[image, Graphics[{Thin, Red, Map[Point, bm]}], ImageSize -> 480]
```

to get a list of pixel positions have the same R G B value (color blue) in the map and in-fact these are the lowest points in the region (according to legend).

But if you apply this hack to the shaded relief map, you got almost nothing. The color code in the legend and the map no longer match. So my question is how to remove the shading effect and use PixelValuePositions like above.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Additionally, can you research what software was used to generate the relief map, and whether the precise algorithm it uses is accessible?  While it may be possible to reverse it, ultimately this is a hack and won't produce accurate data.  I'd only try to do this as a last resort ...

Comment: I edited my question. I know this is very difficult and I am ok with the approximate results. Thanks a lot!